# How to redirect a cancel button to destination on each form?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using the following code to add a cancel button on every form I have for add / edit of every content type. The target should be the destination adress in the url

In some content types it is working and some not:

```
$link = l(t('Annuleren'), drupal_get_destination());

      // add the actual button to the form
      $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
        '#type'   => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Annuleren",
        '#access' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 55,
        '#submit' => $link,
        '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        );

      dpm ($form);
```

It has something todo with #value. If I replace it to #markup like below example then it is working but I do not get a label in the button.

```
  '#markup' => "Annuleren",
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code above, you're using wrong value for `#submit`. `#submit` accepts an array of submit callback function names, check [e.g. here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#submit_property).

You can either add a link in form, which will take user to destination and style the link to look like a button. Check example below:

```
function _custom_form() {
  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<div class="form-cancel-button-wrapper">' . l(t("Cancel"), 'URL', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('form-cancel-button')))) . '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

**OR** you can create a normal submit button and add a custom submit handler which will take user to destination. Check example below:

```
function _custom_form() {
  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value' => "Cancel",
    '#weight' => 55,
    '#submit' => array('_custom_form_cancel')
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  );

  return $form;
}

function _custom_form_cancel($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('URL');
}
```

**Note:** When you define a custom form element, you don't need to give `#access` property specifically, it is `TRUE` by default.

Comment: You'd better use `$form_state['redirect'] = 'redirect-to-this-path';` to the submit handler instead of [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x). Read [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30911/what-is-the-purpose-and-differences-between-drupal-goto-drupal-redirect-form) for details.

Comment: @mchar, yes, we can use `$form_state['redirect']` as well, but since its a cancel button, we can use `drupal_goto()` as well because there is nothing which will be stopped from executing after user clicks on cancel.

Comment: Totally agree! but what if you want to hook to that redirect from another module later on?